# Showing User Names (stored in ASP.Net Core Identity system), instead of IDs When loading a table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've having a lot of trouble doing what you would assume a simple task.
Changing user IDs to username when showing a table at my web application.
This is the data retrieved form the table:(unnecessary information removed)

```
var data = (from o in _mainDbContext.blog
                        select new blogViewModel
                        {
                            Id = o.id,
                            title = o.title,
                            Editor= o.editorID,

                        } );
```

`editorID` is the user ID created by ASP.Net Identity system. I need to load the corresponding user name and place it inside Editor fields for all the entries fetched.

---

What I have tried so far:

Something like:

```
var data = (from o in _mainDbContext.blog
join u in _userManager.Users on o.editorID equals u.UserName
                        select new blogViewModel
                        {
                            Id = o.id,
                            title = o.title,
                            Editor= o.editorID,

                        } );
```

Doesn't work because EF Core doesn't support joining tables from different contexts.

Using `foreach` like:

```
foreach (var row in data)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(row.editorID);
                row.Editor= user.UserName;
            }
```

Doesn't work. It doesn't change the information inside data.

Trying to use raw SQL did not help either. Because `FromSql` works only on one table and `ExecuteSqlCommand` does not work with SELECT.

Comment: If `editorID` is a FK to `AspNetUser` table, why don't you add navigation property and use it to access user related fields in queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `EF Core` don't support query multiple `DbContext` with one query. You could trace this behavior [Query: Throw if second context instance is used in single query #11101](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11101).

For a workaround, you may consider convert `_userManager.Users` to `_userManager.Users.ToList()` which is a list object.

```
            var data = from o in _mainDbContext.Blogs
                    join u in _userManager.Users.ToList() on o.EditorID equals u.Id
                    select new BlogViewModel
                    {
                        Id = o.Id,
                        Title = o.Title,
                        Editor = u.UserName
                    };
        var result = data2.ToList();
```

Comment: Works very well. Although it is a workaround  that burdens the web server instead of  SQL Server but it will not matter that much in my project. Most Likely the best answer. Things are so easier when working with raw SQL that I do not understand the point of EF.

Answer (score 1):

Why are your contexts separated ? Why not merge them and create a relation with a navigation property between Users and Blogs.

```
public class MainDbContext: IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}

public class Blog 
{
    //Some properties

    public int EditorId { get; set; }

    public AppUser Editor { get; set; }
}
```

With this you can easily access user's info via the navigation property `Editor`.

Comment: I preferred not to merge Identity context with my own but it is not that necessary. Can you please provide a sample code of reading/writing with this form?